# Update Openlayers 3 markers all at once on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have twenty markers to update on map. I add the markers and have a function called changeMarker() which changes the marker location. But that function runs for twenty times and so UI is updated twenty times.Can I update the UI only once with all twenty markers together?

Here's my code:

```
function callChangeMarker()
{
     for(var i=0;i<20;i++)
     {
        //value of lat and long changes for all twenty markers
        changemarker(lat, long, markerColor, flag);
     }
}

function changemarker(lat, long, markerColor, flag) {

            var myFeature = vectorSource[flag].getFeatureById('greenMarkerFeature');

            myFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(ol.proj.transform([+long, +lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
}
```

So basically there are twenty such markers with different latitudes and longitudes. I want to update all at once. How to achieve this?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You already are doing all 20 feature modifications without a re-render in between.

OpenLayers does not re-render in any data modification methods. Just like `ol.Map#render`, all that happens is that ol3 knows that a re-render will be necessary in the next animationFrame.

Comment: setting the coordinates to new projection transform does not re-render 20 times??

Comment: @Akansha Correct. To verify, listen to the maps `postrender` event.